# How can I implement a RecyclerView and a CardView into a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm very new to Android Studio and I'm building an app that has a sidebar with icons that lead to fragments. After following a couple of tutorials, the sidebar is implemented and the icons each lead to a fragment. In one of the fragments I'd like to set up a RecyclerView and a CardView with the ability to make new entries and delete them. I tried following Coding in Flow's tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17NbUcEts9c&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBtTYUuc5Pyo4V7xZ2HNtf4&index=2), however, he is implementing it in the MainActivity, not a fragment. I tried putting them into a fragment using the same code up, which appeared to work fine, until he writes
`View v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent);`

Is there another way to define this inflator? Or possibly another tutorial I could refer too?

Comment: that should work in a fragment too, assuming `parent` is a ViewGroup of sorts...

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with the syntax!? also you should be passing in the context variable in your adapter via the constructor. you can use that `context` variable instead of `parent.getContext()` to access all activity methods. if you are confused still maybe pasting the code which is bugging you will help us giving a better explanation.
Also you said you have a problem with your recycler and cardview, probably you mean to say that you cant access the recyclerview or cardview using `findViewById`? If that is the case you can access them using the view object. Example:

```
View view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent);
RecyclerView recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `attach to root` parameter to false
Inflate your view as below

```
View view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent,false);
```